# How to check interaction effect at various values of the compounding variables?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-visualization, interaction

Suppose an interaction between $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $\hat{y}=\beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 -\beta_3x_1x_2$.

The interaction coefficient is an estimation of the effect at the mean values of the compounding variables. My question is how can I see (plot) the interaction at different values of $x_1$ and $x_2$?

As an example of what I wish to do, in an article I read there is an interaction between `percent of white women managers` ($\beta_1=7.5$) and the `prevalence of some practice in the industry`($\beta_2=3.2$), where the interaction is $\beta_3=-8.4$.

Then a plot is shown to help view the dependency in a finer grained way [image]

My questions:

1. How can such a plot/information be created in R? I saw somwewhere that in stata it can be achieved with the `lincom` command, but I don't have Stata.
2. What is the interpretation the 'effect' values (in the Y axis of the plot above)?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Without more detail about the study your second question may be difficult to answer and your first is off-topic here but may (with a reproducible example) find an answer on R-help or StackOverflow

Comment: @mdewey Hmm.. I don't have more information I was just pointed towards an article as a reference. Regarding the first, my question is really  how to estimate the interaction coefficient under specific values of the compounding variables?